# PDF Download mandatory

Tags: html, pdf, download

When I´am link to foo.pdf -> the pdf will shown in a tab. Other sites give me downloads in a little popup for saving or opening - not in a tab. How can I force the download of these files?

Have somebody an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the server? If so, change the `Content-Disposition` header from `inline` to `attachment`.

Comment: I have and I try it - tx

Answer (score 1):

It works. Change headers in apache2:

1) enable module

```
a2enmod headers
```

2) insert in apache2.conf

```
<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">  
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment  
</FilesMatch>
```

3) restart apache

Comment: Great! I am glad that my comment helped you out! (+1 from me)